# How to sort two array of objects using Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I am sorting 2 arrays of object like this, but I know this is very bad.  Any good approach, like using each method like so? ( I tried, but using each, I am unable to return the object )

```
var O1 = [{'name':'one'}, {'name':'two'}, {'name':'three'}, {'name':'four'}, {'name':'five'}, {'name':'six'}];
var O2 = [{'name':'rat'}, {'name':'cat'}, {'name':'lion'}, {'name':'tiger'}, {'name':'dog'}, {'name':'horse'}];

var sorted1 = _.sortBy(O1, function(item){
    return item.name;
})

var sorted2 = _.sortBy(O2, function(item){
    return item.name;
})

console.log(sorted1, sorted2);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/Qtskg/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can do it without a function at all:

> [**sortBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)   _.sortBy(list, iterator, [context])
>
> Returns a (stably) sorted copy of list, ranked in ascending order by the results of running each value through iterator.  **Iterator may also be the string name of the property to sort by (eg. `length`).**

```
var sorted1 = _.sortBy(O1, 'name'),
    sorted2 = _.sortBy(O2, 'name');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing much inherently wrong with your code besides that you would want to extract that function so that you do not need to declare it twice:

```
function itemName( item ){
  return item.name;
}

var sorted1 = _.sortBy(O1, itemName);
var sorted2 = _.sortBy(O2, itemName);

console.log(sorted1, sorted2);
```